# How do I tell if Apache is restarting?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration, command-line-interface

Trying to restart Apache, and can't tell if it's restarting -- are there logs for the restart, or if I input the commandline to restart should I expect a response (error msg, confirmation, status, etc.)

Never done it before and not sure what's going on.

This is exactly what I'm typing, no $/# before it...

**COMMANDS INPUT:**

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

-- or --

```
apache2ctl restart
```

**CONTEXT:** Commands executed from the root directory, meaning... "cd /"

**RESULT:** Nothing appears to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how Apache and syslog are configured on your machine, it may vary, however with a stock Debian or Ubuntu Apache 2 installation, you'd find the logs in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.  If it's restarting you should clearly see it in the logs.

Additionally, checking the output of `ps`, particularly the start time, you should be able to tell if it has restarted.

One last thing, if you're ever trying to find out if a command you just ran succeeded or failed, try `echo $?`.  It'll print the return code of the last command.  99% of the time 0 is what you're looking for there.

Answer (score 1):

`apache2ctl` should return a non-zero status code on failure. You can be informed of a failure by issuing your start command like this:

```
apache2ctl start || echo 'apache2ctl failed'
```

You should see no output if `apache2ctl` thinks it succeeded.

If you prefer something more concrete (following the maxim of "trust, but verify"), you can check whether apache is actually up and listening for connections with `netstat`, e.g.

```
netstat -anp | egrep -i 'http|apache'
```

If you see lines resembling this, then you're golden:

```
tcp6   0   0  :::80   :::*  LISTEN  1506/apache2
tcp6   0   0  :::443  :::*  LISTEN  1506/apache2
```

Or, if you're not running IPv6, you'll see something more like this:

```
tcp   0   0  0.0.0.0:80   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2341/apache2
tcp   0   0  0.0.0.0:443  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2341/apache2
```

In either case, the key point is that apache2 is LISTENing for incoming connections on the well-known www ports (80, and optionally 443).

Answer (score 1):

Mine creates several [notice] entries in the error.log when I `apache2ctl restart`, starting with "[notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart" and ending with "Apache (list of various modules) configured -- resuming normal operations"

Answer (score 0):

There are several places you can look if apache restart. First syslog in /var/log directory. Second apache logs in /var/log/apache2 directory